# Matrix partial derivative with Torch

Tags: pytorch, tensor, torch, derivative

I have a function as f(t,k)=tk+2tk^2. I want to get partial derivative respect to k for t=[1,2] and k=[2,3]. I Have created a matrix of tensors as follows:
gamma=
[10,21
20,42]

when I try to get derivative of gamma respect to k I expect a matrix 2*2 but torch returns a vector instead. what is the problem?

```
import torch
import numpy as np

t=torch.tensor([1.0], requires_grad=True)
k=torch.tensor([1.0], requires_grad=True)
gamma=torch.zeros((2,2))

def f(a,b): #c is a coeff vector
    global t,k,gamma
    t=torch.tensor(a, dtype=float,requires_grad=True)
    k=torch.tensor(b, dtype=float,requires_grad=True)
    for i in range(2):
        for j in range(2):
            gamma[i,j]=torch.mul(t[i],k[j])+torch.mul(2,torch.mul(t[i],torch.pow(k[j],2)))

a=[1,2]
b=[2,3]
f(a,b)

def dy_dx(y, x):
    return torch.autograd.grad(y, x, grad_outputs=torch.ones_like(y),allow_unused=True, create_graph=True)
    
print(dy_dx(gamma,k))
```

I tried to get the derivative of f(t,k) respect to k for t=[1,2] and k=[2,2]. I expected a matrix as follows:
[9,13
18,26]

but torch returns a vector as follows:
[27., 39.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the PyTorch documentation, the [grad function](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.autograd.grad.html#torch.autograd.grad):

> Computes and returns the sum of gradients of outputs with respect to the inputs.

In order to compute the derivative of a function output with respect to its parameters you should use the [jacobian function](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.autograd.functional.jacobian.html). The following snippet computes the first derivative of the function f(t, k) w.r.t. t and k:

```
import torch

def f(t, k):  
  return t * k + 2 * t *  k ** 2

t = torch.tensor([1., 2., 4.], requires_grad=True)
k = torch.tensor([2., 3.], requires_grad=True)
T, K = torch.meshgrid(t, k, indexing='ij')

gamma = f(T,K)

jacobian_t, jacobian_k = torch.autograd.functional.jacobian(f, (T, K))

dfdt = jacobian_t[jacobian_t>0].reshape(len(t), len(k))
dfdk = jacobian_k[jacobian_k>0].reshape(len(t), len(k))

print(gamma)
print(dfdt)
print(dfdk)
```

The output:

```
tensor([[10., 21.],
        [20., 42.],
        [40., 84.]], grad_fn=<AddBackward0>)

tensor([[10., 21.],
        [10., 21.],
        [10., 21.]])

tensor([[ 9., 13.],
        [18., 26.],
        [36., 52.]])
```

If you are looking for a more efficient calculation of the `jacobian` pass the `vectorize=True` parameter to this function. In addition, this function supports both forward and reverse mode automatic differentiation.